# How to download html file on a click of button in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, internet-explorer-11

I am developing a program in VS2015. I have created a abc.html file dynamically. Now I want a functionality that when user click on button that Html file should open or save in browser.How can i do that?
Code to make a Html file Dynamically is as follows:

Client side as Follows:

```
<asp:button  ID="BtnGenrateHTML" runat="server" text="   Generate HTML  " OnClick="btnAddnew_Click"  />
```

Code Behind As Follows

```
protected void TestThisHTML(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sFileFullName;
        string sFilePath;
        string sFileName;

        string strHTMLGrid = "";


        strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "Dear Customer,<BR><BR> Please provide below OTP to complete registration <BR><BR> ";
        strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "<BR><BR> This OTP is valid for 15 minutes.";
        strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "<BR><BR> With Best Regards - Indiefy";
        strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "<BR><BR> Hi My name is Basant Gera";



        sFilePath = Server.MapPath("");
        sFileName = "abc.html";
        sFileFullName = sFilePath + "\\" + sFileName;
        if (!Directory.Exists(sFileFullName))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(sFilePath);
        }
        // if it exist than to delete it.
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(sFileFullName))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(sFileFullName);
        }

        // If it deleted than we need to create it again
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(sFileFullName, FileMode.Create);
        using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            w.WriteLine(strHTMLGrid);
        }

        fs.Close();
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "fncpopup();", true);
    }
```

Now My abc.Html file is working fine...
Now I want on a click of button this Html file get saved on browser and ask on browser that do you want to open or save it to certain location

```
<asp:button  ID="BtnGenrateHTML" runat="server" text="   Generate HTML  " OnClick="btnAddnew_Click"  />
```

Location in which the file of Html is getting saved---->i have used mappath.server to save it in current directory.

If possible make it save in download folder in our directory of PC.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending this last in response :

```
{...
    ....
    fs.Close();
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=abc.html");
    Response.TransmitFile( sFileFullName );
    Response.End();
    ....
}
```

Comment: Its working Awesome...I have applied it But for knowledge base may I know what is  application/octet-stream and Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=abc.html...Please let me know

Comment: @BasantGera In every request and response between server and client there  are  HTTP headers that contains information about the client browser,requested page ,server 

Here , where adding the `application/octet-stream` as content type to inform the browser of the existence of stream file in a response , so if you replace it by `text/html` browser would understand that this is an html file .
For the `Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=abc.html` we are assigning to the http header the file name (abc.html) and the send it as an attachment (open download prompt window in the browser) .

Comment: you can see about http headers [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/http-headers-for-dummies--net-8039)

please check the answer as resolved if that help you

Comment: ThanKyou very very much.You been wonderfull...Thanxs Again  :->

Comment: You're welcome ! Please mark the answer as resolved ( [like this img](http://i.stack.imgur.com/T8umg.png) )